# Is it possible to obfuscate an Angular project's source code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, obfuscation

I have an Angular project and I would like to know if it's possible to obfuscate the code that rendered the browser, so others cannot copy it.

The Web Project is Angular + TS

And I Would like know if it's possible obfuscate the JS Code that I can view in the browser console

Comment: What do you understand the word "encrypt" to mean?

Comment: You cannot 'encrypt' any JavaScript code; you can *minify* or *obfuscate* it (though minification isn't designed to hide code, just make it smaller). Either of those still allow someone to reverse engineer your code if they really wanted to.

Comment: uglify the code for the client and the user can't see it and can`t copy the code.

Comment: @Aurora0001 What would be the best way to protect my code?

Comment: @Diego, the only way you can protect it really is with a copyright license - any method that makes the code impossible to reverse-engineer also makes it impossible for the browser to run.

Comment: @Diego you should not have edited the question, all comments and answers now seem irrelevant to the edited question. Instead you should ask a new question. Please roll back your edits

Comment: I can't publish new question, and SO recommend edit our worst question.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. The browser needs to understand what you have wrote.

As you already said, the only option is obfuscation, it doesn't make your code safe just harder to read.

Comment: Thanks. Can you say me some plugin to obfuscation the code?